# keyListener on jbutton not working

Tags: java, jbutton, keyevent

I would like to perform some action when **'Enter'** key is press as soon as jbutton is clicked but it is not working, someone help

here is my code

```html
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

      jButton.keyTyped(e);
        
    }
```

key listener function

```html
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        //action
    }
```

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind it - sample code below.

```
public class Test {

    static JButton btnA = new JButton("A");
    static JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    static JFrame jf = new JFrame("test frame");

    static ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jl.setText(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText());
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(400, 400);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jp.add(btnA);
        jf.add(jp);

        btnA.addActionListener(action);
    }
}
```